# is it possible to play music from previously fetched data in android?

Tags: android, audio, android-music-player

I was successful in playing streaming audio. The main problem is that if I move to the seek bar to a previous position the loading starts again. Is it not possible to store data in something like buffer and play audio from there so when we move the seek bar to a previous position the music player uses that buffered data  instead of loading once again. Please give me a suggestion of an architecture/example if someone has done it before.

Again explaining with my problem:

If old data (using byte array,buffered array any sort of storage we can use) is available then music player should be able to use that data else normal loading mechanism is okay.

**Note:**
I have seen web browsers doing this task automatically for mp3 songs so if someone knows how it works then we can implement that solution.

Comment: you can try this : write the stream to a file and instead of playing from stream you play from the file.

Comment: Thanks Naveen. Yes this would solve my issue.You know any tutorial about this?

Comment: You can try it yourself if you run into any problem then we'll see